# How to set Database connection timeout in zend framework 1 via application.ini file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, zend-db, connection-timeout

Currently, I am getting timeout error after 30 seconds if database does not connect. I want the same error after 2 seconds.

I have tried this:

```
Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->getConnection()->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 2)
```

But it is not working and also is I want to solve this problem by `application.ini` file.

I think, I need something like this :

```
resources.multidb.msg.driver_options = "PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT = 2"
```